# Extjs4, How to get selected row store?

Tags: extjs4

I want to draw one grid that base on selected row from the other grid.

and I want to reuse the original grid's store. so I need to filter the store to pick only one.

Is it possible? Or do I have to define store for new grid again?

Ex)

```
var myGrid = this.oriGrid().getSelectionModel().getSelection();

var myWindow = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Test',
    autoHeight: true,
    width: 700,
    layout: 'fit',
    modal: true,
    items: {
    xtype: 'grid',
    columns: [
        { header: 'PK', dataIndex: 'PK', flex: 1 },
        { header: 'FK', dataIndex: 'FK', width: 200 },
    ],
    store: myGrid[0].store // it will show all of list, I want to show only I selected row.
    }
}).show();
```

Anybody know, please advice me~ Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** have two UI elements using same store object with different filters if they are presented at the same time.

You would need to clone store and copy records you need into another instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think better solution here. Is inheriting Store, new store and user filter function with your selection, something like that:

```
 secGridStore = new Ext.Data.Store('YourStore');
 secGridStore.filter({
   filterFn: function(item) { return (item in YourStore) } 
 });
```

Sorry this code is incorrect, but you can see my idea.